# Java Cipher bug?: Need at least 16 bytes of space in output buffer

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Let `en` as encrypt of `data`, let `dest` as decrypt of `en`.

If `dest`'s type is byte[] and its length equals to `data`, success.

But if `dest`'s type is `ByteBuffer` and its length equals to `data`, fail: Need at least 16 bytes of space in output buffer.

But again, if `dest`'s type is `ByteBuffer` and its length equals to `en`, success.

```
@Test
public void testAes() throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(128);
    Key key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    byte[] data = "data".getBytes();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    cipher.update(data);
    byte[] en = cipher.doFinal();

    // success for byte[] type
    byte[] destBytes = new byte[data.length];
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    cipher.update(en);
    cipher.doFinal(destBytes, 0);
    // OK
    Assert.assertEquals(destBytes, data);

    // error: Need at least 16 bytes of space in output buffer
    // If replace data.length with en.length, success:
    // destBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(en.length);
    ByteBuffer destBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    cipher.doFinal(ByteBuffer.wrap(en), destBuffer);
    destBuffer.flip();
    Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.copyOfRange(destBuffer.array(), 0, data.length), data);
}
```

Is this a bug?

There are two points for my opinion:

- It checks dest ByteBuffer's length, but doesn't check dest byte array's length;
- If I exactly know descryption length (such as 5, 17, 31, 49...), I just need allocate exact space, not full block size (16, 32, 48, 64...).

Comment: The answer to "Is this a bug?" when referring to a platform like Java that is extensively used, is generally "extremely unlikely, check your own code and your assumption first".

Answer (score 1):

*Is this a bug?* No, this is correct.

To understand why this is correct you need to look at `en.length` for different length input.

You will notice that `en.length` is 16 for input lengths from 0 to 15.

What that means is that when you call `cipher.doFinal(ByteBuffer.wrap(en), destBuffer);` the decryption code sees an input block of length 16 and needs enough room in `destBuffer` for the decryption of `en` **without knowing** how long the effective length of the decrypted content is (to determine the effective length it need to do the full decryption.)

In the case of the `cipher.update(en)` / `cipher.doFinal()` methods the result of decoding `en` is stored in an internal buffer and finally copied into the output array (if there is enough room in the output array - otherwise you will see the same `ShortBufferException`).

---

To the comment: *Think about it, if I know that length of src data is 5 not 16, I just need allocate 5-bytes-space, rather than 16-bytes-space*

But this is not how AES works. AES is a block cipher that encodes and decodes data in chunks of 16 bytes. That means no matter if your input is only one byte or 15 bytes (maximum 15 bytes for the final block), to decode a block of encoded data the AES cipher code needs a buffer with a length of 16 bytes to decode that block.

Its just that the `doFinal(byte[], int)` method (respectively the code that effectively does the decoding) allocates that buffer internally and then copies the decoded result into your buffer.

It seems that the code working with `ByteBuffer` tries to avoid additional memory allocation as much as possible and the designers decided to rather throw an exception before trying to decrypt than working with to small a buffer.

Two caveats:

- if you provide an output buffer of at least 16 bytes then that additional allocation is not necessary and is skipped.
- if the provided output buffer is shorter than the actual data length you will get an exception.

Comment: But it doesn't check destBytes's length. Think about it, if I know that length of src data is 5 not 16, I just need allocate 5-bytes-space, rather than 16-bytes-space.